# How to generate .html files for route [slug] in Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have a Next.js (version 13.4.5) app with a dynamic route `/blog/[slug]`. I wish to export the app as a static website. Here is the directory structure:

```
/app
  /blog
    /[slug]
      page.jsx
    page.jsx
  layout.jsx
  globals.css
  ...
```

and content of `next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  trailingSlash: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

After I run command `npm run build`, the generated files in `/out` directory are as following:

```
/out
  /.next
  /404
  /blog
    index.html
    index.txt
  404.html
  index.html
  index.txt
  ...
```

**There are no .html files generated for the route `/blog/[slug]`, which is not the same as described in the [official document](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#deploying):**

> When running next build, Next.js generates the static export into the out folder. Using next export is no longer needed. For example, let's say you have the following routes:
>
> /
>
> /blog/[id]
>
> After running next build, Next.js will generate the following files:
>
> /out/index.html
>
> /out/404.html
>
> /out/blog/post-1.html
>
> /out/blog/post-2.html

In previous version I can use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to pre-render pages. But these methods are not supported in new version with new App Router.

How can I generate .html files in new version ("next": "13.4.5",) for route `/blog/[slug]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [generate-static-params](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params)

```
// Return a list of `params` to populate the [slug] dynamic segment
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await fetch('https://.../posts').then((res) => res.json())
 
  return posts.map((post) => ({
    slug: post.slug,
  }))
}
 
// Multiple versions of this page will be statically generated
// using the `params` returned by `generateStaticParams`
export default function Page({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like the pre-render methods have been changed from `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to `generateStaticParams `.

Comment: if you dont use it, that page will be generated as dynamic server component